# Object literal's property 'charts' implicitly has an 'any[]' type in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

ide: vscode

typescript: 2.7.1

react: 16.3.0-alpha.1

```
interface IState {
   data: number[];
}
class RawCanvas1 extends React.Component<undefined, IState> {
  constructor(props: undefined) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    data: []  // this right!
    }
  } 
}

class RawCanvas2 extends React.Component<undefined, IState> {
  constructor(props: undefined) {
  super(props);
  } 
  state = {
    data: [] // [ts] Object literal's property 'data' implicitly has an 'any[]' type.
  }
}
```

But the compiler can infer that the state must have a data:[] field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you redeclare a field in a class you will need to provide a type annotation for it, or the compiler will infer one for you based on assignment, it will not use the type declared in the base class (`React.Component` in this case)

```
class RawCanvas extends React.Component<undefined, { data: number[] }> {
    state: Readonly<{ data: number[] }> = {
        data: []
    }
}
```

Although you are better off initializing the field in the constructor and not redefining it.

Comment: I am sorry that my description is inaccurate.In fact, I did not redeclare a field in a class.I modified question.thanks.

Comment: @Whj It still seems to me you did. In `RawCanvas2` after the call to `super` you close the constructor with `}`, so the next line is `state = .. ` which will be the definition of the field state, initialized with the value after `=`